# Regex to match double underscores?

Tags: python, xml, regex, gedit

I'm trying to extend the `python.lang` file so that it will make methods like `__init__` highlighted. I've been trying to come up with a Regex that will match all `__privateMethods()`.

The `python.lang` is a XML file containing all of the highlighting rules for python files. Ex:

```
<context id="special-variables" style-ref="special-variable">
   <prefix>(?&lt;![\w\.])</prefix>
   <keyword>self</keyword>
   <keyword>__name__</keyword>
   <keyword>__debug__</keyword>
</context>
```

How can I extend this so that it matches double underscores?

---

**[SOLUTION]:** What I added to my `python.lang` file (if anyone's interested):

First off you need to add this line near the top where the styles are defined.

```
<style id="private-methods" _name="Private Methods" map-to="def:special-constant"/>
```

Then you'll add the Regex that [Carles provided in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902509/regex-to-match-double-underscores/4902883#4902883):

```
<context id="private-methods" style-ref="private-methods">
    <match>(__[a-zA-Z_]*(__)?)</match>
</context>
```

And here is what it looks like when your done!

[image]

Comment: woow ! thank you for the report

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should rather be:

```
(__[a-zA-Z0-9_]*(__)?)
```

In order to match all of the following:

```
__hello()
__init__()
__this_is_a_function()
__this_is_also_a_function__()
__a_URL2_function__()
```

Comment: Thanks I figured out how to add it.

Comment: @Carles: I updated my answer to show how it can be added. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Lucas nice... but you ended up using Mikhail's regex ;)

Comment: @Carles: Whoops! I copied the wrong section of the file. I actually did end up using yours. ;)

Comment: @Carles: I just noticed a bug. Your solution doesn't match words with uppercase letters. I've updated the regex in my question to fix that.

Comment: @Lucas hm yes it did match uppercase. Anyway I just updated it to also accept digits after looking at http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

Comment: at this point, it's simpler to just go with `(__[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)` if your final `__` is optional anyway. they match the same things and the main difference is whether you need a capture on `__`.

Answer (score 1):

Match your previous case piped with the following ([rubular example](http://www.rubular.com/r/hxqI9KrvGH)):

```
(^__[a-z]*__$)
```

Comment: @Mikhail I think it should be (^__[a-z]+__$) to prevent matching ____.

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound: No I actually want it to match the second set of underscores as well.

Comment: @Lucas McCoy you mean matching four underscores?

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound: I'm going to match `__methods()` and `__methods__()` so his regex is ok. I'm going to modify it a little.

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound: That looks great, but when I add `()` it doesn't match. I don't want the parenthesis to be highlighted but it needs to match everything before them. Also you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Lucas McCoy changed to \w and added \(\) at the end(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_character_classes) http://regexr.com?2t1k7